# What DNS is my Powerdns recursor using?

Tags: dns, ubuntu-12.04, nameserver, linux-server

I just setup a powerdns recursor under a clean Ubuntu 12.04 server.  I didn't notice any difference in query times (using dig) so I looked at my `/etc/resolv.conf` file.  I left `nameserver=127.0.0.1` but commented out `nameserver=172.16.1.254` which is my router/dns.  Now `dig` shows a noticeable improvement in query times so all is good.

I only downloaded the recursor, and it seems that I have removed the nameserver address from my server.  My question is, how is my server able to resolve names?  The `recursor.conf` file has no external domain setting, and the server doesn't know where any nameserver is so how can dig work at all?  Sorry if I am missing something obvious but I am trying to learn more about linux and servers by diving right in.

Comment: This is a guess as I have never used the software so leaving as a comment, maybe it is querying the root name servers itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive DNS server have a built-in list of the IP addresses of all root servers. The rest of DNS descends from the roots.

(If it would forward all queries to another nameserver, it would be called *forwarding*, not *recursive*)

Comment: Perfect!  I setup the recursor with the intention of using it as a chaching nameserver.  I guess that made me think that it was still forwarding but had a memory for the IPs it already resolved.  I researched both forwarding and recursing nameservers now and know the difference.  I also found out that my recursor was not being used because it was listed after my router in the resolv.conf file.  Thanks for the help.